# Campo select com primeiro item em branco

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Utilizo `select` e ele vem preenchido do banco:

```
    <select asp-for="CategoriaID" asp-items="@Model.CountryList" id="cbcategoria" class="form-control">
                    </select>
```

E aqui é como está no controller:

```
model.CountryList = new SelectList(countries, "Id", "Value");
```

Gostaria de saber como posso deixar os select sem preencher ao inserir um novo registro? O campo é required na ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um option com a opção `disabled` para que ele não seja selecionado.

```
<select asp-for="CategoriaID" asp-items="@Model.CountryList" id="cbcategoria" class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected>Selecione</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer que o primeiro item do select seja branco, você pode fazer no load da página.

```
$("#cbcategoria").append("<option id='option_cbcategoria' value='' selected>" + "" + " </option>");
```